# Safely culling or consolidating Time Machine backups on a full backup volume

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have a Mac with a connected 1tb SSD for Time Machine backups. Today I received the dreaded message that the Time Machine volume was full, so it can't create any more backups.

I am only using 500gb of my primary volume, and no other volumes are backed up. Time Machine has made a daily backup for the last 18 days and more frequent backups since then.

You'd think that Time Machine could (a) automatically consolidate old incremental backups to make space for newer incremental backups (e.g., every other daily backup more than a week old), or (b) at least give the user some way of picking backups to delete in the Time Machine UI. Unfortunately, neither is the case. The official suggestion is to [buy a new drive and connect it in place of the current one](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-the-time-machine-backup-disk-is-full-mh15137/mac), which is quite disappointing (and likely guarantees a recurrence, at which point I'll need a third drive...?)

Of course, many people have encountered this problem and have sought advice. The only common response is to use `tmutil delete` to delete individual, incremental backups manually. My concern is that this seems likely to compromise the integrity and dependability of later backups.

For instance, given this incremental backup set:

```
Backup #1 (January 1st): File A (v1), file B (v1)

Backup #2 (January 2nd): File A (v2)

Backup #3 (January 3rd): File B (v2)
```

...if I happen to delete Backup #2, then I think that the manifest for Backup #3 will show that it includes v2.0 of File A, but because I deleted the backup in which File A was changed to v2.0, it's no longer available. So if I later wanted to restore my volume from Backup #3, the restore would likely fail due to a corrupt incremental backup set.

This scenario could be avoided if `tmutil delete` were smart enough to *consolidate* backups while deleting them - e.g., moving File A (v2) from Backup #2 to Backup #3. However, I cannot find any indication that it does that. My guess - and concern - is that `tmutil delete` just dutifully wipes out Backup #2 as I requested, and if that step happens to corrupt Backup #3, that's on me. `tmutil` won't help me avoid that problem, and I would be likely to discover the problem only upon trying, and failing, to restore Backup #3.

I would even buy a commercial product that offers additional options to manage Time Machine backups, but I didn't find any that looked trustworthy.

What do?

Comment: Some of this depends on what macOS you're running & therefore whether your TM drive is HFS+ or APFS. That move would be safe on HFS, I'm not so sure on APFS. Apple used to recommend FInder copying to a larger drive, but no longer.

Comment: First, have you opened your backup drive in the Finder?  On mine, there is a folder called Backups.backupdb.  It's possibly not a real folder, but it looks like one in Finder.  Mine has 2 sub-folders there, for the 2 Macs I've connected this drive to.  I've seen (a while ago) where TM would create a 2nd backup set for the same Mac, maybe after an OS change, or a Mac machine name change.  Check to make sure you don't have an extra backup set.  But the TM preferences literally tell you that it throws away old backups when out of room, which I can confirm is true for me.

Comment: I recommend starting with the articles linked on https://eclecticlight.co/consolation-t2m2-and-log-utilities/ for understanding how TM works. The HFS+ and APFS backing storages behave quite a bit differently (e.g. HFS+ allows removal of individual files). And yes, https://eclecticlight.co/2020/01/17/time-machine-9-inside-backup-support-files/ says the db is a real folder.